# Get browser's current position using selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, ruby

I would like to know if there's any way to know the absolute position of the browser's visible canvas.
Ex: if I'm at a webpage and I scroll down 200px, I would like to know I'm on the coordinate {X,200}.

Is there a way to do this using Selenium Webdriver?

Thanks

PS - I know that the Element has the property Position, which returns his absolute position on the page. I'm not sure if this may help, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been asked a few times on StackOverflow and every answer I found points to using [JavaScriptExecuter](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/JavascriptExecutor.html).

- StackOverflow [Example 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25733877/selenium-how-do-you-check-scroll-position)
- StackOverflow [Example 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12293158/page-scroll-up-or-down-in-selenium-webdriver-selenium-2-using-java)

Comment: Thanks Kirbycope, but what I'd like to know is in which position I am when I go to the bottom of the page, and not to scroll there. But this will be useful anyways, thanks!

Comment: The same principle applies. You can use the JavaScriptExecuter to get the values you need. Here is an example, http://stackoverflow.com/a/3464890/1106708